# How to get the port number a program is listening on in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I have a program (beam) running, and I need to figure out which TCP / IPv6 port it is listening on. I know `netstat` will tell me, but I haven't fully been able to parse its output:

```
RABBIT_PORT=$(netstat -tupln | grep beam)
echo $RABBIT_PORT
```

Gives:

```
tcp  0 0 0.0.0.0:47858 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 4533/beam 
tcp6 0 0 :::5672       :::*      LISTEN 4533/beam
```

But I need to extract just the port number (5672), how can I do so? Alternatively, is there a better command than `netstat` to do this (that'll be as widely available as `netstat`, at least on Linux?)

Comment: What do you want, extract data from netsat ? listen to a port ? singing in the rain ? it's really unclear what you want. Please [edit] your question for either formatting and makes clearer what you want.

Comment: i want 5672 port, how to get the particular port using netstat

Comment: Do you realize that what you say means nothing ? I want a port using netsat ? and I want color using /dev/urandom please try to express precisely what you want, and [edit] your question in consequence. Because you can extract the port number by using grep, for example. So please what do you mean **precisely** ?

Comment: RABBIT_LIST=$(netstat -tupln | grep beam | awk '{print $4}')

echo $RABBIT_LIST.... Output: 0.0.0.0:47858 :::5672 Now i want take 5672 only how to print 5672  using shell script

Comment: As you find a solution it's OK, but 3 persons has edited your question to rephrase and format what you wanted. please next time try to format your question and give sense to it. You don't want to print `5672` you want to extract the listenning port of beam on ipv6. If you had written this, you would have get your answer in 2 minutes. next time please try to express thing in a general way and not a very specific example that makes no sense.

Comment: thanks slm, Anthon, rahmu, Timo, Zelda. Always you all given more negative points.. If you know the answer share to the people who doesn't, don't discourage those people.  You all are human being ??

Comment: Just so you know, I personally did not downvote or even vote to close. All I did was edit to change one wrong tag. Those who voted to close, did so because the could not understand your question. If they had known the answer, your question would not have been unclear. They  voted to close because they couldn't understand what you were asking. Next time, please show your desired output so we can understand you.

Comment: Whenever i post a question to the forum they simply downvote my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
netstat -6tnlp | awk '/\/beam / {print $4}' | tr -d :
```

There's probably a neater way, and that line depends on there being only one IPv6 socket bound to a process called `beam`.

Comment: This will be failed with ipv6 localhost address `::1`

Comment: @terdon if you're getting `0.0.0.0` (a v4 address), you've probably missed the `-6` option from `netstat`

Comment: @Flup quite right, I was just parsing the OP's example, good point, +1.

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange that you only want to get listening port from `IPv6`. Try:

```
netstat -6tupln | grep beam | awk '{gsub(".*:","",$4);print $4}'
```

or:

```
ss -tln6 | grep beam | awk 'NR!=1{gsub(".*:","",$4);print $4}'
```